# SELENIUM & JAVA - Ecommerce Application - Unable to remove product from the cart page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

**With the below code, I am able to remove only the first product from the cart page but not all the products**

public class RemoveProductFromCart {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://askomdch.com/account/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("testuser1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Password@123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and @name='login']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

*Clicking on the cart icon==>*

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ast-desktop-header']//div[@class='ast-cart-menu-wrap']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

*Grouped all the items to remove into a list and then click them one by one to remove all the products==>*

```
    List<WebElement> removeList = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'shop_table')]//a[@class='remove']"));

    for (int i = 0; i < removeList.size(); i++) {
        removeList.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if (removeList.size() == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the first product from the cart the remaining products are rearranged there so the remaining `WebElements` in the `removeList` list becoming stale elements.
In order to remove all the products from the cart you have to get the `removeList` again after each time the product is removed and validate there are still products in the cart, as following:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
List<WebElement> removeList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'shop_table')]//a[@class='remove']"));
while(!removeList.isEmpty()){
    removeList.get(0).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.blockUI.blockOverlay")));
    Thread.sleep(200);
    removeList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'shop_table')]//a[@class='remove']"));
}
```

Comment: I modified according to your suggestion but after removing the first product, it is now giving another exception. 

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="https://askomdch.com/cart/?remove_item=a58149d355f02887dfbe55ebb2b64ba3&amp;_wpnonce=81d78d79b4" class="remove" aria-label="Remove this item" data-product_id="1208" data-product_sku="">...</a> is not clickable at point (219, 348). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: Right, there is a spinner there. You should wait for that spinner disappear before continuing. Will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Please let me know if now it works correctly for you

Comment: I happy to know :)